# Jquery can't get form data in opera

Tags: jquery

**It appeared that the problem was not Jquery related but html related:**

I rendered the form between a table row. Then I tried rendering the table row in the the form.
Opera and Firefox only accept that you render a complete table between form tags.

Invalid:

```
<form>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

or

```
<tr><form>
<td></td>
</form></tr>
```

Valid:

```
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I can't understand why in Opera and IE the following code does not work...

```
$("#form_" + $(this).attr('id')).serialize();
```

I checked it by only getting the attribute; worked
I checked if I could get the form data without serialize; worked

How should I code this? Tried a lot of combinations and stuff but nothing works.. why does this isn't working in opera? In chrome I have no problems...

**To answer some of the questions below**

I have multiple forms on my page, each with an unique id (from_1, form_5 etc.) I checked this and is correct. The form data needs to be fetched when a select changes, so data call is fired by an change event.

Comment: Why you add prefix "form_" to your form id? Because as I can see this is your form. So use $(this).serialize()

Comment: Does your form actually have an **id** attribute that looks like "form_xxx" (where "xxx" is the id of `this`)? Are you sure that your "id" values are **unique** on the page (no two elements share the same id value)?

Comment: @CoolEsh: What about a button that has the ID "calculation" and a form with the ID form_calculation? I also use that alot

Comment: some additional info in the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem;

I rendered the form between a table row. Then I tried rendering the table row in the the form.
Opera and Firefox only accept that you render a complete table between form tags.

Invalid:

```
<form>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

or

```
<tr><form>
<td></td>
</form></tr>
```

Valid:

```
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code in Opera 11.01:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function serializeFormData( formId )
        {
            var serializedData = $( '#form_' + formId  ).serialize();
            alert( serializedData );
        }
    </script>
<body>
    <form id="form_1" name="form_1">
        <input type="text" name="form_1_input" value="1" />
        <textarea name="form_1_textarea">1</textarea>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="serializeFormData( 1 )">Serialize</a>
    </form>

    <form id="form_2" name="form_2">
        <input type="text" name="form_2_input" value="2" />
        <textarea name="form_2_textarea">2</textarea>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="serializeFormData( 2 )">Serialize</a>
    </form>

    <form id="form_3" name="form_3">
        <input type="text" name="form_3_input" value="3" />
        <textarea name="form_3_textarea">3</textarea>
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="serializeFormData( 3 )">Serialize</a>
    </form>
</body
</html>
```

And everything works fine for me!!!